# Why does the Oracle have no idea what happen to the Keymaker for some time?

Tags: the-matrix

> The Oracle: **I know you’re not sleeping**. We’ll get to that. Why don’t
>   you come and have a sit this time?
>
> Neo: Maybe I’ll stand.
>
> The Oracle: Well, suit yourself.
>
> ...
>
> The Oracle: Then Zion will fall. Our time is up. Listen to me, Neo.
>   You can save Zion if you reach The Source, but to do that you will
>   need the Keymaker.
>
> Neo: The Keymaker?
>
> The Oracle: Yes, he disappeared some time ago. **We did not know what
>   happened to him until now**. He’s being held prisoner by a very
>   dangerous program, one of the oldest of us. He is called the
>   Merovingian, and he will not let him go willingly.

The omnipotent Oracle knows Neo can't sleep well but has no idea what happen to the Keymaker for some time. Why is that?

Since she can predict future, why couldn't she predict it before the Merovingian had him?

Comment: It's possible that the Trainman had him.

Comment: But she knows the Trainman has Neo in M3. I don't know if the train station is a blind spot for her. Even if it is, she can reasonably infer that if someone falls out of her reach it must be the Trainman.

Comment: Possibly from the same source that told her about the Keymaker.

Answer (score 2):

I have two hypotheses

First, I think it likely that the Oracle didn't have the sight at all. It could be that she just collected and kept data on the happenings throughout the versions of the Matrix, and for this reason she has 'seen it all before'.

Second. There is the possibility the Architect was telling the truth. If you remember the scene where Neo meets with the Architect? A video is shown of the other 'versions' of Neo, each reacting differently. And he clearly explains that 'The One' is just another form of control. Machines aren't given to lying, there would be no point. So it could be the Oracle is just a factor within this failsafe.

Comment: If the Oracle didn't have the sight, why would the Merovingian ask for her eyes?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37137/why-did-the-merovingian-destroy-the-oracles-shell Asks something along the same lines. Why does he do anything he does? Well, how about to rebel against his original coding? To wreck havoc with the plans of the architect? To destroy the humans once and for all? To get back at Neo for one slight or another? @KinzleB

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle is very far from omniscient (and also very much not omnipotent). She can read Neo like a book right from the first moment they meet. This doesn't change. She was conceived with the singular purpose to understand humans.

That's why she can easily read that Neo has trouble sleeping.

Now, to your actual question. Two points:

1. She doesn't always speak the truth. She says what you *need to hear*.
2. Her job is not to understand machines. And you can bet the Merovingian has some nifty tricks up his sleeve to hide information (the most valuable commodity he possesses).